# lz4 compression algorithm explaination

Tags: compression, lz4

Can some one explain me the lz4 algorithm with an example byte array and how that is compressed? I am unable to understand how the compression algorithm is working and how it is so fast and still so promising about the compression ratio.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See http://fastcompression.blogspot.in/2011/05/lz4-explained.html